# Make carousel slider from last 5 posts product from related category with prev and next button

Tags: featured-post

I have more than 5 products in the same category. I want to display all related products in a slider form on a single product page. For desktop display, use the next and previous buttons. Meanwhile, the mobile display simply uses a sliding system.

Here is the php code of the related product I created.

```php
<?php
$categories = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'product-category');

if( $categories ):
    $category_ids = array();
    foreach($categories as $category) :
        $category_ids[] = $category->term_id;
    endforeach;

    $argss = array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'post__not_in'   => array(get_the_ID()),
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'tax_query'      => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product-category',
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => $category_ids,
            )
        )
    );

    $relateds = get_posts( $argss );

    if( $relateds ): ?>
        <div class="labelbox">
            <div class="newest">
                <h3>RELATED PRODUCTS</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="boxcontainer clear product-related">
            <?php
            foreach( $relateds as $related ): ?>
                <div class="productbox clear">
                    <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($related->ID); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title($related->ID); ?>">
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="thumb">
                                <img class="lazy" data-src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($related->ID, 'full'); ?>" width="100%" height="auto" alt="<?php echo get_the_title($related->ID); ?>">
                            </div>
                            <div class="title">
                                <h3><?php echo get_the_title($related->ID); ?></h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="pricing">   
                                <?php
                                $price = get_post_meta($related->ID, 'product_price', true);
                                $price_custom = get_post_meta($related->ID, 'product_price_custom', true);
                                $price_slik = (int) get_post_meta($related->ID, 'product_price_slik', true);
                                
                                if( $price_slik ): ?>
                                    <span class="price_slik"><del>Rp <?php echo number_format($price_slik,0,',','.'); ?></del></span>
                                <?php
                                endif;
                                if( $price ): ?>
                                    <span class="price">Rp <?php echo number_format($price,0,',','.'); ?></span>
                                <?php
                                endif;
                                if( $price_custom ): ?>
                                    <span class="price"><?php echo $price_custom ?></span>
                                <?php
                                endif; ?>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            <?php
            endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    <?php
    endif;
endif; ?>
```

please help me, I've tried to find a way but didn't find a solution. Thank you for your help

Comment: Is your question that you want to display all products instead of only 5? It's unclear from your post. If you'd like to have every product displayed, change the `5` in `posts_per_page` to `-1`, which tells WordPress to grab every post available instead of just a limited number.